# Plaintext message space in Somewhat Homormorphic Encryption scheme?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

**Question 1:** In which Somewhat Homomorphic Encryption schemes the plaintext space is defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

It is said, in Somewhat homomorphic encryption the noise increases when homomorphic multiplication is used.

**Question 2:** Does this include multiplying a ciphertext by a plaintext? or just multiplying two ciphertexts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer to question 1**

I don't know about any somewhat (or leveled) homomorphic encryption whose plaintext space is the field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Several schemes work over the ring $\mathbb{Z}_t[x] / \langle f(x) \rangle$, which is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ when we chose $t$ to be a prime $p$ and $f(x)$ to have degree $n$. However, for security reasons, we usually are not able to chose $n = 1$.

Schemes based on integers usually have the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the plaintext space and they do not seem difficult to adapt to an arbitrary prime instead of $2$.

**Answer to question 2**

Yes, multiplying a ciphertext by a plaintext increases the noise.

Ciphertexts in these noisy schemes are (roughly speaking) of the form $f(m) + e$, where $f$ is some function, $m$ is the message, and $e$ is the error. When we multiply a ciphertext $c = f(m) + e$ by another message, let's say $m'$, we end up with something like $f(m) \cdot m' + e\cdot m' = f(m \cdot m') + e'$, and this new error $e'$ is bigger than the original error $e$.

For instance, considerer the YASHE scheme:

- Ciphertext format: $c = \Delta m + e + hs$, where $h$ is the public key, $e$ and $s$ are random polynomials.
- When we multiply by a plaintext $m'$: $c \cdot m' = \Delta m m' + e m' + hsm' = \Delta m m' + e' + hs'$.

As it is said on page 11 of [SEAL's manual](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/sealmanual.pdf#11), for the FV scheme "*plain multiplication increases the noise by a constant factor that depends on the plaintext multiplier*".

And I am quite sure it also happens on plain multiplication of BGV scheme.

Comment: You are right with the second one. I had a mistake in the proof. I will write a detailed answer a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for question 1:**

According to [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/889) popular FHE schemes like BGV, NTRU and so on support plaintexts from a ring $R_p = Z_p[X]/\langle f(x) \rangle$ where $n = deg(f)$. The main trick is that the encryption noise should be a multiple of $p$ and the decryption is done by applying the reduction modulo $p$ instead of $2$.

**Note**: Although the plaintext space is a polynomial ring $R_p$ you can always encode your message $m$ as the free coefficient i.e. $m = x^0 \cdot m + x^1 \cdot  0 + \dots x^{n-1} \cdot 0$. One can argue that this is not really efficient because some coefficients are not used.

Fortunately there are some plaintext packing techniques ([see Section 1.1)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/566.pdf) - a cool way to split the ring $R_p$ in sub-fields $F_p^d$ for which $d$ is a divisor of $n$ (this includes the case $d=1$).

You can view it as operating on contiguous sequences of length $d$ on an array of length $n$ and doing multiple encryptions at the same time.

---

**Answer for question 2:**

Additions and multiplications with public constants are (almost) for free in the FHE world, at least for BGV. Take for example the encryption from [BGV scheme](http://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/6892-Fall2013/BGV.pdf) (page 12) instantiated with RLWE:

Consider $c \in R_q^{2}$ an encryption of $\textbf{m}_1 = (m_1, 0)\in R_q^{2}$. If we multiply the first component $c_1$ with a public constant $\textbf{m}_2 = (m_2, 0)$ and then decrypt using the secret key $s = (1, t_1)$ we get $m_1 \cdot m_2$.

Why? Use the fact that $b = Bt +2e$.

$c \cdot s = c_1 \cdot 1 + c_2 \cdot t = \\
m_1 \cdot m_2 + m_2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N}b_ir_i - t \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{N}B_ir_i = \\
m_1 \cdot m_2 + m_2 \cdot r^t \cdot 2e
$

Now if we reduce the last term mod $R_q$ and then mod $R_2$ we obtain $m_1 \cdot m_2$.

In this way we obtained $Enc(m_1 \cdot m_2)$ starting from $Enc(m_1)$, $m_2$ and added noise by a factor of $m_2$. This is better than encrypting $\textbf{m}_2$ and then do a homomorphic multiplication with a quadratic noise.

Bonus: Addition between $Enc(m_1)$ and $m_2$ can be done with **zero noise**!